# How to use the code above in React js using hooks

Tags: reactjs

```
document.getElementById("cards").onmousemove = e => {
  for(const card of document.getElementsByClassName("card")) {
    const rect = card.getBoundingClientRect(),
          x = e.clientX - rect.left,
          y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    card.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", `${x}px`);
    card.style.setProperty("--mouse-y", `${y}px`);
  };
}
```

I actually don't know how to use the above code in react js. so, if anyone knows please respond!

full source code link:

https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/pen/MWQeYLW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use Hook you need to handle with reference of element like this

```
  const CardRef = React.useRef(null);
  useShadow(CardRef);

  return <div ref={CardRef} className="card"  ></div>
```

And the hook would be something like this

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useShadow = (reference: React.MutableRefObject<any>) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventReference = (e) => {
      const rect = reference.current.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

      reference.current.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', `${x}px`);
      reference.current.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', `${y}px`);
    };

    if (reference.current) {
      const { current } = reference;
      current.addEventListener('mousemove', eventReference);
    }
    return () => {
      reference.current &&
        reference.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventReference);
    };
  }, [reference]);
};

export default useShadow;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, React does provide [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)s, so your `onmousemove` would probably look like this in React:

```html
<div onMouseMove={ yourEventHandler } />
```

I can see what you are trying to do is to set the children `.card`'s properties when the mouse had moved. What you can do is to have `useState()` in the parent `.cards` container to store the latest mouse position, then pass that state as props into the children. Something like:

```js
export function Cards() {
  const [mouseX, setMouseX] = useState(0);
  const [mouseY, setMouseY] = useState(0);

  const myOnMouseMove = (e)=> {
    // set your state using setMouseX(), setMouseY()
  }


  return (
    <div className='cards' onMouseMove={myOnMouseMove}>
      <Card className='card' mouseX={mouseX} mouseY={mouseY} />
      <Card className='card' mouseX={mouseX} mouseY={mouseY} />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

(Not real implementation, just the concept)